# R - assigning value to vector based upon matches to one of multiple lists

Tags: r, performance

I have a data frame with a vector containing text strings.  I am trying to recode these strings into a value (0, 1, 2, ...) based upon whether each string is contained in one of several lists, and assign to a new vector within the data frame

For example:

```
vector = c( "A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
list1 = c("B", "G", "P", "Z")
list2 = c("A", "E", "M", "Q")
list3 = everything not in list1 or list2
```

The new vector should assign "0", "1", or "2" according to whether vector[i] is contained in list1, or list 2, or list3:

```
new_vector = (2, 1, 3, 3, 2)
```

I've tried various permutations of %in%, but the problem is that "vector" is extremely long (hundreds of thousands of elements), and some of the lists against which I'm matching are also fairly long (10-30 elements).  I've got statements that work, but are *EXTREMELY* slow.  Watching moss grow kind of slow.

What are the R "tricks" for optimally speeding up a convoluted matching scenario like this?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should store your lists together in a single object, not with numbered names:

```
L = list(list1, list2)
```

Then you can use data.table for fairly fast matching:

```
library(data.table)
LDT = rbindlist(lapply(L, data.table), idcol = TRUE)
vDT = data.table(v = vector)

vDT[, id := LDT[vDT, on=.(V1 = v), .id]]

#    v id
# 1: A  2
# 2: B  1
# 3: C NA
# 4: D NA
# 5: E  2
```

There is no need to create a list for "everything not in the other lists." It can just be assigned NA, as seen here.

If your lists aren't disjoint, this will break in weird ways, so you may want to set up a rule to stop if that's the case:

```
stopifnot( !anyDuplicated(LDT[, "V1"]) )
```

---

*How it works*

LDT and vDT are tables and the syntax for a join is `x[i,on=,j]`. The join uses `i` to look up rows in `x`. `j` is some value computed using the matching rows (here, just one of the columns from `i`).

To assign columns, use the `j` argument like `colname := expression`. See [the website](http://r-datatable.com) for details.

Comment: OMG, that works incredibly well!.  Thanks, Frank - you really saved my hide!
That's definitely a trick I'm putting away into my personal library.